# HTML Helpers not working after sending blank value in textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am banging my head for the last 3 hours and I don't know what is wrong.

My question is, Why HTML helpers are not working when I submit a blank value in `ProjectCode`. Below are my View and Controller?

View:

```
@using Models;
@model LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/_MainTheme.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProjectCode)
    <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" />
    <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Details", "NewSurvey")
    <br />

    <div style="display:@(Model.SurveyList.Surveys.Count > 0 ? "block" : "none");">
        <div>@Model.SurveyListTableHeader</div>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Project Code</td>
                    <td>Project Name</td>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var survey in Model.SurveyList.Surveys)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@survey.Value.ProjectCode</td>
                    <td>@survey.Value.ProjectName</td>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        Session["CurrentPage"] = ePages.Login;
        LoginViewModel login = new LoginViewModel();
        login.SurveyList = BusinessOperations.GetExistingUserSurveys("mp12672", ref ScreenMessages._Message, ref ScreenMessages._MessageStateID);
        login.SurveyListTableHeader = "Recently Accessed Surveys";
        return View("Login", login);
    }

    public ActionResult Search(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        Session["CurrentPage"] = ePages.Login;
        login.SurveyList = BusinessOperations.GetProjectSurveys(login.ProjectCode, ref ScreenMessages._Message, ref ScreenMessages._MessageStateID);
        login.SurveyListTableHeader = "Surveys matching your search";
        return View("Login", login);
    }

    public ActionResult Resume(string SurveyKey)
    {
        Session["SurveyKey"] = SurveyKey;
        return RedirectToAction("Introduction", "OMS");
    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on the below line

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Details", "NewSurvey")
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? What is not working?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just added the exception details at the end. When I keep the `ProjectCode` text box blank and click on `Search` button, I get that error.

Comment: No, that line is not throwing the exception. But what possibly is is the `@(Model.SurveyList.Surveys.Count` line if either `SurveyList` or `Surveys` is `null`

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke, you are correct, my SurveyList.Surveys was null due to an error in my DAL module and it had a try catch block already, so I couldn't catch it.